# TXS0108E as bus isolator?

Tags: hobbyist

I've been looking for a Bi-directional IO isolator to "unplug" a microcontroller during startup, and found the TXS0108E.

My question would be: **can you tie VCCA = VCCB = 3.3v?** according to the datasheet VCCA ≤ VCCB so the supplies COULD be equal, but the datasheet is so focused on the "level shifting" feature it completely ignores the bus isolation feature (Pull OE low to place all outputs in 3-state mode).

If this IC in not appropriate for this task then any suggestions would be appreciated, I'm just a hobbyist so I don't know all the lingo, making research harder. All the ones I could find were either level shifting or not fully bidirectional (direction defined by pin)

Comment: Why don't you tell which MCU it is, and why it needs unplugging during startup, and unplugging from what - rather than asking if device X is suitable for unplugging.

Comment: The datasheet says you can, so why would you think otherwise? If you don't need level shifting though, you might want to look for something called a bus transceiver, which is the proper name for what you're using this as.

Comment: @Justme The MCU is an ESP8266 and the "device" is a couple of SPI modules and a couple of relays. During startup the ESP8266 does some wild stuff with the IO(like not boot on some cases or drive the inputs). I omitted this info because it didn't seam relevant, and I probably don't even need it

Comment: @Germán Of course everything is relevant. The chip you propose is mainly meant for level shifting of bi-directional open-drain buses. It needs very specific conditions to work, and if you don't provide the specific conditions it won't work. SPI is not an open-drain bus, and it can't drive a couple of relays either (most likely you are not driving the relays directly, but you did not say how either). Expect issues if the relay driver input is not a logic IC, but a transistor. Why put a bidirectional IC when you don't need one?

Comment: @Hearth all bus transceivers that I saw only allow one direction for the entire bus, and the direction is defined by a pin, that's why I was looking at the TXS0108E, because the pins can go in one direction or another with no setup and independently for the rest(which I think doesn't qualify as bus)

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please edit new information into your question, don't post it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece all of this together to understand what's being asked. (Please rewrite the question text as needed to contain this info, don't just dump it at the end under an 'EDIT' heading.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to disconnect some signals is a switch. These devices are typically called "analog switch" because they work not only with digital signals.

There are eight-channel devices like the SN74CBTLV3245A (note: "CBT" devices without "LV" do not support rail-to-rail signals), or you can combine cheaper four-channel devices (anything called 74xxx4066).